# [rosrun] Couldn't find executable

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, beginner-tutorials, rosrun, catkin-ws

[image: Rosanswers logo]

//www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/ExaminingPublisherSubscriber.

When I try to run rosrun beginner_tutorials talker. It tells me that:
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named talker below /home/MY_NAME/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials

Additional information: When I ran find -executable -type f the output is given as below:

```
./src/beginner_tutorials/talker.cpp
./src/beginner_tutorials/listener.cpp
./devel/_setup_util.py
./devel/env.sh
./build/catkin_generated/stamps/Project/_setup_util.py.stamp
./build/catkin_generated/installspace/_setup_util.py
./build/catkin_generated/installspace/env.sh
./build/catkin_generated/setup_cached.sh
./build/catkin_generated/env_cached.sh
./build/CMakeFiles/feature_tests.bin
./build/CMakeFiles/3.5.1/CompilerIdC/a.out
./build/CMakeFiles/3.5.1/CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_CXX.bin
./build/CMakeFiles/3.5.1/CompilerIdCXX/a.out
./build/CMakeFiles/3.5.1/CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_C.bin
```

After using the env | grep ROS_PACKAGE_PATH I get:

ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/MY_NAME/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/kinetic/share

and I have sourced the file using the following command:
source ./devel/setup.bash

below is the CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(beginner_tutorials)

## Compile as C++11, supported in ROS Kinetic and newer
# add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
)


################################################
## Declare ROS messages, services and actions ##
################################################

## To declare and build messages, services or actions from within this
## package, follow these steps:
## * Let MSG_DEP_SET be the set of packages whose message types you use in
##   your messages/services/actions (e.g. std_msgs, actionlib_msgs, ...).
## * In the file package.xml:
##   * add a build_depend tag for "message_generation"
##   * add a build_depend and a exec_depend tag for each package in MSG_DEP_SET
##   * If MSG_DEP_SET isn't empty the following dependency has been pulled in
##     but can be declared for certainty nonetheless:
##     * add a exec_depend tag for "message_runtime"
## * In this file (CMakeLists.txt):
##   * add "message_generation" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
     find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS 
    roscpp
    rospy
    std_msgs
    message_generation
     )
##   * add "message_runtime" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
     catkin_package(
    ...
        CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime ...
        ...)
##   * uncomment the add_*_files sections below as needed
##     and list every .msg/.srv/.action file to be processed
##   * uncomment the generate_messages entry below
##   * add every package in MSG_DEP_SET to generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES ...)

## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
 add_message_files(
   FILES
   Num.msg
 )

generate_messages()

## Generate services in the 'srv' folder
 add_service_files(
   FILES
   AddTwoInts.srv
 )

## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
 generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES
   std_msgs
 )

catkin_package(
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
include_directories(
 include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)




add_executable(talker src/talker.cpp)
target_link_libraries(talker ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(talker beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)

add_executable(listener src/listener.cpp)
target_link_libraries(listener ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(listener beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)

add_executable(add_two_ints_server src/add_two_ints_server.cpp)
target_link_libraries(add_two_ints_server ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(add_two_ints_server beginner_tutorials_gencpp)

add_executable(add_two_ints_client src/add_two_ints_client.cpp)
target_link_libraries(add_two_ints_client ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(add_two_ints_client beginner_tutorials_gencpp)
```

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302658/%5Brosrun%5D-couldn%27t-find-executable/) by [YSY](https://answers.ros.org/users/37364/ysy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2018-09-07

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-09-07**:
as no executbale is found, seems that you did not build the node as described in [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29). What makes no sense, though, is that the `talker/listner.cpp` are executable. This is not python :-)

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-09-10**:
I took the liberty of reformatting the question and get rid of a lot of the comments.

Two things are strange.

1. if this is a 1-to-1 copy of your `CMakeLists.txt`: you call `find_package` twice. I'm not sure if this is even possible or what the effects are.
2. If no `talker` executable is found ..

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-09-10**:
in `devel`, the compilation was not succesfull. You did call `catkin_make` again after adding the respective `*.cpp` files, right? You have to call those every time you change something.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-10**:
@mgruhler wrote:

> you call `find_package` twice. I'm not sure if this is even possible or what the effects are.

It won't work.

It needs to be removed / the second call needs to be merged with the first.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-09-10**:
Thanks for clarifying.

I suspected as much but have not tested it and didn't have the time to investigate.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-10**:
Well to be fair it does "work", but almost never does what the user expects. It's infinitely better and more intuitive to not have two `find_package(catkin ..)` statements in there.

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2018-09-16**:
Has this been solved yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. Are you trying to run a python node? You need to make it executable via `chmod +x yournode.py` and put it into the `scripts/` folder or your package.

There is a set of best practices for setting up your workspace with Python nodes that I can't manage to find right now.

2. If it's a C++ node, the problem is usually that it's not listed in your CMakeLists.txt as a build target. I don't think this is your problem, but maybe someone else's who will come across this.

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2018-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [YSY](https://answers.ros.org/users/37364/ysy/) on 2018-09-07**:
it is a C++ node
i have add the code below into CMakeLists.txt before

add_executable(listener src/listener.cpp)

target_link_libraries(listener ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

add_dependencies(listener beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2018-09-07**:
Please add all the relevant CMakeLists.txt parts to the question. Can you do tab completion on "rosrun begin" and "rosrun beginner_tutorials lis" after sourcing? What exactly is the error?

**Comment by [YSY](https://answers.ros.org/users/37364/ysy/) on 2018-09-08**:
CMakeLists show at the questions.  it will show out rosrun beginner_tutorials after tab completion
i have no idea what the error is??

**Comment by [YSY](https://answers.ros.org/users/37364/ysy/) on 2018-09-10**:
??????????????

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2018-09-10**:
Please don't spam punctuation marks, everyone is a volunteer here. Would you mind formatting the file as code? There is a button in the editor.